# Gradle: How to upload custom JAR file to Maven repository

Tags: maven, jar, gradle

I build a jar file without using Gradle Jar task (I need to be using Ant task for that inside my task). How do I configure uploadArchives to be able to install JAR in specified repository.

I have tried to override default artifact with

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            // some Maven configuration
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives file: file('bin/result.jar')
}
```

but I'm getting an error that there may not be 2 artifacts with the same type and classifier, which means this configuration adds rather that overrides configuration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right, `artifacts` closure can only add artifacts to the given configuration (see [ArtifactHandler API](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/ArtifactHandler.html)).

You have two options:

1) Add an artifact filter as described [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#uploading_to_maven_repositories) (see ch. 45.6.4.1. "Multiple artifacts per project"). If you use this, try declaring your `archives` configuration like:

```groovy
artifacts {
  archives file: file('bin/result.jar'), name: 'result', type: 'jar'
}
```

This way, you something like this in your artifact filter:

```groovy
addFilter('result') {artifact, file ->
  artifact.name == 'result'
}
```

2) Upload it as a separate maven module. If `result.jar` is the only jar you are uploading this may be a good solution.

```groovy
configurations {
  resultArchives
}

uploadResultArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "same/url/here")
    }
  }
}

artifacts{
  resultArchives file: file('bin/result.jar')
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The latter worked in my case as a charm.

Comment: I get an error Gradle DSLmethod not found 'uploadResultArchive' , I have applied plugin  maven. Any other plugin required

Comment: @sver I guess he meant _uploadArchives_

Comment: Does this create a pom.xml?